# Excel: Using a dropdown to query a data table within the workbook

Tags: excel

I currently have an excel data table that I would like to query.

The table has seven columns:

1) User Name
2) QC Date
3) Client
4) State
5) Product
6) Order ID
7) Status

I also have a data validation dropdown that lists every User Name.

I am trying to create a macro/code that would display column 1, column 2, column 6 and column 7 based on the dropdown selection. Filters does not work because I am displaying the data on a different worksheet.

I am rather new to VBA and excel data tables and any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: If you're displaying the data on a different worksheet, why not put the filters there instead?

Comment: if by "dropdown selection" you mean a data validation list, you can use ranges on other sheets only if you use `named ranges`.  That is, apply a name to the range containing the values you want in your drop down, and specify that name as the validation list range.

Answer (score 0):

1. As Chris mentioned, use range naming.  Name USER column (highlight the column) as USER

[to name a range ... look at the field to the left of the "formula bar" at the top of the screen. You probably just see cell names "A1" "A2" etc when you select those cells. This is where you name a range. After you highlight the USER column, type USER in this box. It's now named.]

1. Select a new sheet tab (or use another worksheet/workbook).
2. On the other tabbed sheet (or other spreadsheet/workbook) where you want to display the data, in the first cell type **='USER'$a$1**  for example.  (Or, to not show if the cell is empty:  =if('USER'$a$1="","",'USER'$a$1)
3. copy/paste this cell to the others below it.
4. do the same for the others you want to have displayed on this new tabbed page.
5. select the tab where you entered the data.  Right mouse click the tab and select **hide**  Assuming the users are novices, they won't know where to find the data.